# ZF2 doesn't use params while redirecting

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I have a problem with routing in my app.

```
$this->redirect('someone', array('controller' => 'account', 'action' => 'settings'));
```

It always redirects to app.dev/someone doesn't matter what is in array.

I have found that problem is in method **assemble** from **TreeRouteStack.php**

*TreeRouteStack.php:347*

```
$path = $this->baseUrl . $route->assemble(array_merge($this->defaultParams, $params), $options);
```

I tried "die" before this line to test $params - everything is ok. So `die(implode(',',$params));` before code above *returns*

> account, settings

But after this `echo $path` *returns*

> /someone

instead of

> /someone/account/settings

Where could be problem? I'm using ZF2 2.2.2

Comment: can you post the route you have for `someone`? Is it a segment route? Does the segment route contain parameters `:controller` and `:action`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$this->redirect()->toRoute(
    'someone',
     array('controller' => 'account', 'action' => 'settings')
);
```

instead of

```
$this->redirect(
    'someone',
    array('controller' => 'account', 'action' => 'settings')
);
```

Please take a look at [Redirect Plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-redirect) in zf2 docs